# Counting words with letters from TOWN with conditions

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

Show that the number of $m$-letter words using letters T  O W  N (maybe not using some of them) in which the number of Ts and Os are equal, is equal to the number of $2m$-letter words only using Ts and Os and where the number of Ts and Os is equal.

I guess the second number is $C^ m_{2m}$ but don't know how to count the first one and tp tie them together.  Also tried small $m$ number cases and they all seem true.

Comment: Why do you start all your questions with "beautiful"?

Comment: @Irvan Probably to trick us to look at it. Only to be somewhat disillusioned when we do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you have found, the number of $2m$-letter words is easier to count, and that number is $\binom{2m}{m}$, since it equals the number of ways to choose $m$ places for the $T$s.

To show the number of $m$-letter words is the same, it suffices to show a bijection exists between the two sets of words.

Let $S_1$ be the set of $m$-letter words and $S_2$ be the set of $2m$-letter words, as defined in the question.

Define a function $f:S_1 \rightarrow S_2$ by a map of individual letters, as follows:

\begin{eqnarray*}
T &\mapsto& TT \\
O &\mapsto& OO \\
W &\mapsto& TO \\
N &\mapsto& OT \\
\end{eqnarray*}

It is fairly easy to see that this is a bijection but to fill in the details of proving it:

**$f$ does map $S_1$ to $S_2$:**

For any $w_1 \in S_1$, $w_1$ has $m$ letters so it's clear that $f(w_1)$ has $2m$ letters. It's also obvious that $f(w_1)$ consists only of $T$s and $O$s and that, since $w_1$ has the same number of $T$s and $O$s, $f(w_1)$ has the same number of $TT$s and $OO$s and hence the same number of $T$s and $O$s. So $f(w_1) \in S_2$.

**$f$ is $1-1$:**

$f$ being $1-1$ follows from the individual letter mapping above being $1-1$.

**$f$ is onto:**

Let $w_2 \in S_2$ and $1 \leq i \leq m$. The pair of letters taking positions $2i-1$ and $2i$ in $w_2$ must be one of $TT$, $OO$, $TO$ or $OT$; hence, one of the letters $T$, $O$, $W$, $N$ maps to it. Construct a word, $w_1$ having its $i^{th}$ letter that particular $T$, $O$, $W$ or $N$. Since $w_2$ has the same number of $T$s and $O$s, it must have the same number of $TT$s and $OO$s and this is the same as the number of both $T$s and $O$s, respectively, in $w_1$. Also, it's obvious $w_1$ consists of exactly $m$ letters in $\{T,O,W,N\}$, so $w_1 \in S_1$.

Thus, $f$ is a bijection and the result is proved.